# Jackson: How to parse comma-separated String values to String[]

Tags: java, string, csv, jackson

Is there a way to tell Jackson-Objectmapper to parse a comma-separated String to a String[]?

Answer (score 0):

Jackson has module [`jackson-dataformat-csv`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-csv) for parsing CSV data.

Just use its [`CsvMapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-csv/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/csv/CsvMapper.html) instead of plain `ObjectMapper`. For example:

```
String s = "aa,bbb,c,dd";
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new CsvMapper();
String[] array = objectMapper.readValue(s, String[].class);
```